# Unable to install my own created laravel package

Tags: laravel-5

Few days ago I created a laravel package using guide provided in this [link](http://kaltencoder.com/2015/07/laravel-5-package-creation-tutorial-part-1/) and submitted it to packagist.org website. They provided me a composer code to install it. You can find the package [here](https://packagist.org/packages/mansa/simplepay). When I tried to install it using composer and it is giving me following error.

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package mansa/simplepay at any version for your 
minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

Can you please tell me how can I install this package?

I am using Ubuntu with PHP 7.0 and laravel 5.3.6. 
I am not much familiar with laravel.

Comment: Right now you can install it like this `composer require mansa/simplepay dev-master`. You need to release a stable version.

Comment: Thanks man. It worked.

Comment: Is it going to properly install the package or do I need to add some dependencies manually as well?

Comment: If you use some third party libraries in your package you should add them as dependencies.